# Formation of coordination complexes?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

I'm having trouble understanding how exactly coordination complexes are formed.

Compounds such as $\ce{[Cu(H2O)6]++}$ are the ligands filled into the empty 3 of 4p orbitals+ 1 of 5s orbital + 2 of 4d orbitals or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to analyse a compound, it is best to start with the $d$-electron count of the metal. For $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ we get $d^9$, since $\ce{Cu^0}$ would be $d^{11}$.

Now, consider the following (simplified) molecular orbital diagram for a $d^1$ compound:
[image: Molecular orbital diagram for a $d^1$ complex.]

As you can clearly see, the ligand electron pairs mix with some of the $d$, the $s$ and $p$ orbitals of the metal.

Now, instead of $d^1$ we have $d^9$, so we just start filling in 8 more electrons into the MOs. This gives us a full $t_\text{2g}$ MO and 3 electrons in the $e_\text{g}$ MO. ($t_\text{2g}$ and $e_\text{g}$ are ways of describing the symmetry of the orbitals. This comes from applied group theory.)

So you see, the $5s$ orbital never comes into play here, only the $3d$, $4s$ and $4p$ orbitals of the metal take part in bonding.

You might want to look at [Ligand Field Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand_field_theory) and [Molecular Orbital Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital_theory) to further your knowledge in inorganic chemistry. Not everything is as simple as the "fill in the boxes" method.